# How to move product data to another website view

Tags: magento-1.7, php, database

I need to show the products from my Main website to my second website.
What i am doing right now is i check the second website checkbox under product catalog tab "Websites". I have thousand of products and it means i need to check it one by one. Is there easiest way to do this in magento? or what is the database table that i need to update. I already update "catalog_product_website" and it showing in the backend but it is now showing on my frontend. Please help
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this from the Product grid.

Filter the grid to include only the products you want to do this to. Once you've down that, choose Select All. Then, select from the drop-down near the top right of the grid labeled Actions and choose Update Attributes and click Submit. There should be a website tab on the left which you can do this across all the selected products.

[image: Demonstration]